# Looking about fuel pump fuse in my Toyota starlet 1992

Tags: toyota, starlet, tercel

Please if some one can help me. Recently I discovered that no pressure arises from the pump, I wanted to check the fuse or the relay but I couldn't recognize it. Here is a photo of the external fuse box in my car.

[image]

This is the internal fuse diagram photo:

[image]

Comment: I don’t remember there being a dedicated fuel pump fuse on these older toyotas usually they iirc used the circuit cut relay and maybe the am2 fuse. As part of a larger circuit.

Comment: If you are worried about it being a fuse but cannot find one which is exactly for it ... *check all of them* ... and the relays as well.

Comment: Its actually called the circuit opening relay and it pulls power from the efi relay and fuse on usdm toyotas.